# Translation into Koine (perhaps Testament?) Greek

Tags: ancient-greek, greek-translation, koine-greek

Could someone translate the following into Koine Greek (or Testament Greek, if there were juicy differences.)

> We won’t tell Helen why we could leave her at the beach without company.
> The older man we were talking about last night had come to our shop to ask us if we knew Charikleia.

---

(I understand it might be too much to also ask for a similar translation into Homeric Greek;  possibly using, without meter,   ἐννέπω ;  οὕνεκα ; δύναμαι ; λείπω ; θίς ; ἄτερ ; ἑταρία ; γεραιός ; εἴρω ; ἱκνέομαι ; πυνθάνομαι ; ἐρέω ; οἶδα).

I did the Attic translation,  poorly, but I might not be as helpless there... Here is my (attempted) Attic translation, in case it helps:

> Οὐκ ἐρῶμεν τῇ Ἑλένῃ πρὸς τὶ οἵοὶ τ᾽ἦμεν τὴν καταλείπειν αἰγιαλῷ ἄνευ κοινωνίας. Ὁ πρεσβύτης περὶ οὗ  χθὲς ἑσπέρας διελεγόμεθα  τῷ ἡμετέρῳ πωλητηρίῳ ἐληλύθει ἐρέσθαι ἡμᾶς εἰ τὴν Χαρίκλειαν γιγνώσκοιμεν.

---

My tentative Koine gambit is

> Οὐχ᾽εἴπωμεν τῇ Ἑλένῃ διατί ἠδυνήθημεν ἐγκαταλείπειν αὐτὴν ἐν τῇ παραλίᾳ ἄνευ κοινωνίας. Ὁ  γέρων  περὶ οὗ χθὲς ἑσπέρας διελεγόμεθα τῷ πωλητηρίῳ ἡμῶν  ἐληλύθει ἵνα ἐρωτήσῃ ἡμᾶς εἰ τὴν Χαρίκλειαν γινώσκωμεν.

Could a biblical scholar fix it up? I suspect the choice of terms for shop, beach, discuss a person, etc, are subtly off...

I'm using it as a lark illustration of the radical syntax shifts involved.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Can you provide your Attic translation? It is likely to be a useful reference for anyone working on a Koine version.

Comment: Thanks! I took the liberty to edit that into your question. I only know very, very basic Greek, but we have people here who can certainly help.

Answer (score 2):

I won't venture a Koine translation, but if it's useful, here's another Attic version:

> οὐκ ἐρῶμεν τῇ Ἑλένῃ διὰ τί αὐτὴν μόνην ἐν τῷ αἰγιαλῷ κατελίπομεν· εἰσῆλθε γὰρ εἰς τὸ ἐμπόριον ὁ πρεσβύτης περὶ οὗ χθὲς ἑσπέρας διελεγόμεθα ἐρωτῶν εἰ Χαρίκλειαν γιγνώσκοιμεν.

(I changed "why we could leave her" to "why we left her" since I wasn't sure exactly what the former was intended to mean.)